# After xcodegen, screen size is not full screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodegen

When I had just created a project, the screen looks fine and it reflected exactly what I saw looked on the storyboard, and after pod install also look good. But after xcodegen generate, screen looks like the pic, so I assume xcodegen affected the screen view but not sure what has been changed. project.yml only contains dependency packages.
Does anyone know what makes screen size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It happens when there is no launch screen specified. In your `project.yml`, add something under `UILaunchScreen`, like this:

```yaml
targets:
  MyApp:
    type: application
    platform: iOS
    deploymentTarget: "15.0"
    sources: [MyApp]
    info:
      path: MyApp/Resources/Info.plist
      properties:
        UILaunchScreen:
          UIImageName: LaunchImage
```

where `LaunchImage` is the name of an image in your asset catalogue. Alternatively, specify a color with UIColorName. That color also has to be in your asset catalogue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UILaunchStoryboardName` key

[image]